# Mac os permissions prevent me to delete files

Tags: macos, security

I installed easy_install on mac wityh the following command:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | sudo python
```

After that I tried to install pip but couldn't.
After checking here is what I have in /usr/bin

```
$ ls -l easy*
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  925  7 Jan  2016 easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  454  7 Jan  2016 easy_install-2.6
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  461  7 Jan  2016 easy_install-2.7
```

Probably it does not work because I have 2 versions installed now. I am in the list of sudoers but even with sudo I cannot delete these files:

```
sudo rm -f easy_install-2.6
Password:
rm: easy_install-2.6: Operation not permitted
```

When I log in to this macbook there is my username and also Administrator which I do not have access to now.

Is there a way to be able to delete these files without having to wait until the person that has the password for Administrator comes back from vacation?

Here is my macbook info

```
  System Version: OS X 10.11.6 (15G31)
  Kernel Version: Darwin 15.6.0
  Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
```

Thanks

Comment: I'd bet this would get more, and more appropriate, attention and answers in [Think Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/). Besides, [the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) of SO is programming and this is quite far removed from that (programming does not boil down, in this case, to installation of programming tools).

Comment: @Sami, makes sense. Thanks